# VBA select shapes based on their positions

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

How do I select all shapes (array? range?) where the value in Cell `"A:Shape.TopLeftCell.Row" = 0` ?
[image]

The Array should consist only Shapes 2 and 3 as per image above.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  I ask this, because it is *rarely* necessary to `Select` or `Activate` anything in Excel.

Comment: Also, this doesn't make any sense: `"A:Shape.TopLeftCell.Row" = 0`.

Comment: of course it does not. It is to show that I need shapes which a placed in such way that their top left corner is in a row, where in a column A value = 0.

Comment: Select I mean put in an Array so then I'll perform some changes to all of them

Comment: OK. Then what have you tried so far? You can create a function that will return an array of shape names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as an alternative, you can reverse the logic and select as you go, then assign the selection to a shaperange if required:

```
Sub ShapePicker()
    Dim s As Shape
    Dim sr As ShapeRange
    Dim i As Long

    i = 1
    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Cells(s.TopLeftCell.Row, "A").Value = 0 Then
            s.Select (i = 1)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next s
    Set sr = Selection.ShapeRange
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Build a **ShapeRange** that meets the criteria and then Select that **ShapeRange**

```
Sub ShapePicker()
    Dim s As Shape, sr As ShapeRange
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Set mycell = Range("A:A").Find(What:=0, After:=Range("A1"))
    rrow = mycell.Row

    i = 1
    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If s.TopLeftCell.Row = rrow Then
            ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To i)
            Arr(i) = s.Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next s

    Set sr = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Arr)
    sr.Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the shapes on the sheet until you find one in the range. As someone else mentioned, selecting is often unnecessary.

```
Dim shp As shape
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.shapes
    If Not Intersect(yourselectedrange, shp.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
         shp.Select
         Exit For
    End If
Next shp
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way around of this. I came across this post while looking for a solution.

So here it is the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56609670/5720144) for anyone looking for a way around.

The Method goes like this:

Run a `loop` like this once to change the names of the `Rectangles` to the Address of their `TopLeftCell`

```
 Dim sh As Shape

 For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes

    sh.Name = sh.TopLeftCell.Address

 Next sh
```

---

Now in any other code you can directly access the shape using:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveCell.Address).Select
```

This is one way you can achieve it. Though there doesn't exist a method that you are looking for.

You can change the `ActiveCell.Address` any range object or maybe just the text itself. It will take values like `$D$4`

Tried and Tested, it works Smoothly.