# "Select all shapes" gives Excel VBA Error 438 -- "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet that organizes, stylizes, and summarizes data, and then copies itself and saves another copy as a .PDF.

On the original sheet, there are 3 "Buttons" made out of groups of shapes to run different macros ("Reset", "Fix Missing Employees", "Print and Email Summary". **The problem is in deleting them on the copy.** This is from a recorded macro:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 2")).Select
Selection.Delete
```

I want to select/delete ALL shapes. I can't use "shapes.select", "shapes.delete", or anything else I've found help for. Every attempt beside the code listed above results in "Error 438 -- Object doesn't support this property or method" and it highlights that portion of the code.

How can I select/delete all shapes in a worksheet/book? (Using Excel 2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to select all the Shapes in a worksheet to delete them.  A loop will do:

```
Sub ShapeKiller()
    Dim sh As Shape
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        sh.Delete
    Next sh
End Sub
```

You can delete more than one Shape at the same time.  Here is an example that finds a certain row and deletes all the Shapes whose upper corner is in that row:

```
Sub ShapePickerAndKiller()
    Dim s As Shape, sr As ShapeRange
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Set mycell = Range("A:A").Find(What:=0, After:=Range("A1"))
    rrow = mycell.Row

    i = 1
    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If s.TopLeftCell.Row = rrow Then
            ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To i)
            Arr(i) = s.Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next s

    Set sr = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Arr)
    sr.Select
    Selection.Delete
End Sub
```

See [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288149/vba-select-shapes-based-on-their-positions)

Comment: Perfect! That's just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the final solution I used:

```
Dim sh As Shape
For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If sh.Type <> msoPicture Then
        sh.Delete
    End If
Next sh
```

The reason is because I had one shape I wanted to keep, with a logo of the company--The Shape Object approach made it very easy to handle this, because of the `Shape.Type` attribute (As one shape was a msoPicture, and the rest were msoRoundedRectangles). Also helpful, had there been one picture I wanted to delete would have been `Shape.Name` to name the one to delete or skip.

Shout out to @Gary's Student for pointing me down this path!