# Can you select a shape directly, if you know its topleftcell row & column

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I have approx. 100 rectangles on a sheet. I want to change the color of a particular rectangle for which I know its `TopLeftCell` co-ordinates.

I want to be able to directly select this rectangle to change its color, but I cannot find any VBA code to do this. Currently, the only code I can find, selects all shapes on the sheet, and then looks for an intersection of each of the shapes on the sheet with the `TopLeftCell`, to then select that rectangle to change its color.

With maybe 100 shapes to check, this seems a very inefficient method, and I think there must be a better way.

```
Dim sh as shape

For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Not Intersect(Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumber), sh.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
        sh.Select False
        Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
    End If
Next sh
```

I wonder if a code like

```
selection.shape.topleftcell(cells(RowNumber,ColumnNumber))
```

or similar would be possible in VBA.
I tried this and other like code, but all give errors.

Comment: There is one other Work Around for your Problem. Run a loop once and change the names of all the shapes according to `sh.Name = sh.TopLeftCell.Address` ... Now in your any other code you can access the Shape using `Cell.Address` without having to loop through them and remembering any Id's or anything like that.

Comment: In general: As many elements (shapes in this case) can directly be addressed *only* either by their name or index, looping often is a standard method. Checking 100 ranges is not as time consuming either, so nothing against that. In this case: @Mikku found a nice workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are doing is `Select`ing the shape you wish to change the color, then merely:

```
Sub changeColor()
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

IF you want to access other properties of the Shape in a more organized fashion, I would suggest collecting the Shape names in a Dictionary with the TopLeftCell as the key.  Then you can do something like:

```
Option Explicit
'Set Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Public dShapes As Dictionary
Private Sub refShapes()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim SH As Shape

Set WS = ActiveSheet
Set dShapes = New Dictionary
    dShapes.CompareMode = TextCompare
For Each SH In WS.Shapes
    dShapes.Add Key:=SH.topLeftCell.Address, Item:=SH.Name
Next SH

End Sub

Sub changeColor()
    Dim SH As Shape
    Dim topLeftCell As String

topLeftCell = Selection.topLeftCell.Address

refShapes

If dShapes.Exists(topLeftCell) Then
    Set SH = ActiveSheet.Shapes(dShapes(topLeftCell))
    SH.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 255)
    SH.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    SH.Fill.Solid
Else
    MsgBox ("No shape at that location")
End If
End Sub
```

**However**, this technique will fail if you have more than one shape with the same `TopLeftCell`, but could be adapted to handle that situation if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Run a `loop` like this once to change the names of the `Rectangles` to the Address of their `TopLeftCell`

```
 Dim sh As Shape

 For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes

    sh.Name = sh.TopLeftCell.Address

 Next sh
```

---

Now in any other code you can directly access the shape using:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveCell.Address).Select
```

This is one way you can achieve it. Though there doesn't exist a method that you are looking for.

You can change the `ActiveCell.Address` any range object or maybe just the text itself. It will take values like `$D$4`

Tried and Tested, it works Smoothly.