# Find last row that is empty, insert picture (code not recognising cells with images in already)

Tags: excel, vba

So my code currently works like this:

- User clicks insert button
- Button launches a file browser
- User selects file (an image)
- The code assigns a variable (filename) to the file path
- It then inserts a rectangle shape on the last empty row
- The image fill is made to be the image the user selected via the file path

Works without any issues, apart from the following. (where I say image, it is actually a rectangle shape with an image fill)

When there are no images in the column, and the user hits the button for the first time, it inserts an image into the correct cell (the first one that is empty).
However when the user goes to select the 2nd image, it puts it in the same cell as the first.

I've worked out that it isn't recognising a shape/image being in a cell as containing value.

If I entered some text into the first cell, then clicked the insert button, it will put the image into the cell below, as it should.

Is there a way to ensure the cell recognises that when a shape is inside it then the cell has value and for the code to look for the next cell below?

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow_num = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow_num = LastRow_num + 1
EmptyRow = "C" & LastRow_num

Dim filename As String
filename = Application.GetOpenFilename

Dim clLeft As Double
Dim clTop As Double
Dim clWidth As Double
Dim clHeight As Double

Dim cl As Range
Dim shpRec As Shape

Set cl = Range(EmptyRow)

clLeft = cl.Left
clTop = cl.Top
clHeight = cl.Height
clWidth = cl.Width

Set shpRec = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, clLeft, clTop, 370, 240)


    With shpRec.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .UserPicture (filename)
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
    End With
```

(the reason the LastRow_num has a +1 is because the code finds the row with the last value, whereas I need it to point to the last EMPTY row)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The position of images/shapes can be determined by their [`.BottomRightCell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.bottomrightcell). Using `End(xlUp)` won't work here. I think there are several questions here on SO that demonstrate the approach. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288149/vba-select-shapes-based-on-their-positions) uses `TopLeftCell`, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to implement that within my code when it's an if statement. The way I had it before was it would assign the empty row to a variable, then I was able to call on that variable later in the code where I tell it where to insert the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've worked out, "it isn't recognising a shape/image being in a cell as containing [a] value." In other words, using `.End(xlUp)` won't work here; you can work with the [`Shape.BottomRightCell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.bottomrightcell) and you'll need to loop through the shapes in the worksheet.

Here's a helper function that should do the trick. Note that this might not work if you have text or other values interspersed between the images, but can be modified if that is the case.

```
Function NextEmptyRowForShapes(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal col As Long) As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With ws
        Dim s As Shape
        For Each s In .Shapes
            If Not Intersect(s.BottomRightCell, .Columns(col)) Is Nothing Then
                If s.BottomRightCell.Row > lastRow Then
                    lastRow = s.BottomRightCell.Row
                End If
            End If
        Next s
    End With

    NextEmptyRowForShapes = lastRow + 1
End Function
```

Used like this:

```
LastRow_num = NextEmptyRowForShapes(ActiveSheet, 3)
```

**EDIT:**

This version should handle both shapes and text/values.

```
Function NextEmptyRowForShapes(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal col As Long) As Long
    With ws
        Dim lastRow As Long
        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp)) Then
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
        End If

        Dim s As Shape
        For Each s In .Shapes
            If Not Intersect(s.BottomRightCell, .Columns(col)) Is Nothing Then
                If s.BottomRightCell.Row > lastRow Then
                    lastRow = s.BottomRightCell.Row
                End If
            End If
        Next s
    End With

    NextEmptyRowForShapes = lastRow + 1
End Function
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I was confused by the fact that when I ran the code it started with C1, because C1 has text in it so it shouldn't be considered empty. But then I remembered you had written about it may not working if there is text interspersed between the images. Is this what you mean? What would be the best way to resolve this? Is there a way to have the code check if there is a shape OR text value?

Comment: I'm not sure what I changed on the document to make this happen, I didn't edit any of the code, just did some formatting on the page but I'm now getting the error "The index into the specified collection is out of bounds" - any ideas?

It then highlights the line: For Each s In .Shapes (in your function code)

Comment: Well, Excel crashed and when I reopened it everything seemed to work, so nevermind then!